# How to recover deleted files in linux filesystem (a bit faster)?

Tags: linux

If I launch the following command to recover lost file on linux:

> grep -a -B 150 -A 600 "class SuperCoolClass" /dev/sda10 > /tmp/SuperCoolClass.repair

***Do I really need the "-a"?*** We need to recover from "sda10" some erased files (sabotage) and we have a bunch of them to recover and I believe removing the -a would be faster.

I believe the files to be on disk but not in binary.

thx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file you are working on is `/dev/sda10` which `grep` would assume to contain binary data. In order to treat it as text (which you are looking for) you need the `-a` otherwise `grep` will just print `Binary file /dev/sda10 matches`

In addition since the task is IO rather than CPU bound it would not be a big performance gain in any case.

In the future it's quite easy to test something like this by yourself:

- create dummy 10Mb disk: `dd if=/dev/zero of=testfs bs=1024 count=10000`
- create filesystem: `mkfs.ext4 testfs`
- mount via loopback: `mount -o loop ./testfs /mnt/test/`
- copy some stuff on the dummy filesystem
- unmount: `umount /mnt/test`
- run `grep` on the test file with different options

EDIT
it just occurred to me that maybe you are looking for the command ['/usr/bin/strings'](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_strings.htm) instead

something like:

- extract all printable strings from ruined disk: `/usr/bin/strings -a /dev/sda10 > /tmp/recovery`
- grep on the text only many times for different strings: `grep "whatever" /tmp/recovery > /tmp/recovery.whatever`

Comment: I'm actually looking to recover deleted files, by using GREP which is looking in SDA10 for text I know was located in the files (text files)

Comment: I understand that, by using /usr/bin/strings you will filter out all binary content from /dev/sda10. Subsequent grepping on the text only portion of the data will possibly be faster.

Answer (score 2):

To recover a **text file** (only a text file) you accidently deleted / overwrote (provided you remember a phrase in that text file)

- Ensure the safety of files by unmounting the directory with

  `umount /home/johndoe`.
- Find which hard disk partition the folder is at, say *sda3*
- Switch to terminal as root.
- Run

  `grep -a -A800 -B800 'search this phrase' /dev/sda3 | strings>recovery_log.txt`
- This will take a while. You can go through the file *recovery_log.txt* using any text editor, even while the command is running.

Comment: @code-gijoe the **-a** parameter limits the grep search to only text files.

Comment: how can i find the "Find which hard disk partition the folder is at, say sda3"?

Comment: @user48135 The most straightforward way to find that is running `df` command and compare the columns **Filesystem** and **Mounted on**.